# java function to read a folder of files

Tags: java, function, bufferedreader

I have a program that currently reads in a file, looks for keywords, and outputs the number of occurrences of the keywords. I need to write a function that reads in all the files and I need to insert this function in a spot so that the total number of occurrences is displayed.

I am currently reading in 1 file like this

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\P4logs\\out.log.2012-12-26")))
    {
```

Comment: Do you mean read all the files in a folder, read all files in an array, or create a function that will work with any file?

Comment: Do you want to do this recursively?

Comment: @bmorris591 Yes I think it would be good recursively

Comment: @EAKAE Read all the files in a folder, which are all log files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to get your folder path and then loop through all the files in that folder and have a check that filters out files you don't want.

```
File path = new File(path); //path to your folder. eg. C:\\P4logs
for(File f: path.listFiles()) { // this loops through all the files + directories
    if(f.isFile()) { // checks if it is a file, not a directory.
                     // most basic check. more checks will have to be added if 
                     // you have other files you don't want read. (like non log files)
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f.getAbsolutePath()))) { 
        // gets the full path of a file. so "C:\\P4logs\\out.log.2012-12-26"
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting an error for .listFile it is saying it is undefined

Comment: @user2007843 wups its listFiles() typed too fast

Comment: I think this works, I guess I should manually check the log files though.

Comment: @user2007843 yes. you can do something like if(f.getName().contains("log")) {...}

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

```
File folder = new File("C:/path_to_your_folder/");

for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
  // Got a file. Do what you want.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive function for a recursive search

```
void readAllFiles(final File myFile) {
  if(file.isFile()) {
    //read the file and whatever
    return;
  }
  for(final File childFile : myFile.listFiles()) {
    readAllFiles(childFile);
  }
}
```